# Getting java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC when performing the process between server and client

Tags: java, android

I am building android app by using WiFiP2P method to connect between two devices and apperantly one is server and one is client ,So  In the the following code I am trying to read objects from ObjectInputStream but it crushes with StreamCurruptedException , please help me to figure it out! By the way I checked some other answers ,but it did not help me to find out the bug.

```
   This is receiving thread :

         @Override
    public void run() {
        while (socket != null) {
            try {
                try {
                    if(socket.isConnected()) {
                        Object object = inputStream.readObject();
                        if (object != null) {
                            if (object instanceof Opponent) {
                                final Opponent opponent = (Opponent) object;
                                PlayOnline.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        TextView username = users_layout.findViewById(R.id.user_single_username2);
                                        username.setText(opponent.getName());
                                        ImageView imageView = users_layout.findViewById(R.id.user2_single_image);

                                        if (opponent.getGender().equals("Female")) {
                                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fuser1);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                hideBar();
                            } else if( object instanceof GamePoint) {
                                GamePoint point =(GamePoint) object;
                                Message message = new Message();
                                message.what = 3;
                                message.obj = point;
                                handler.sendMessage(message);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


   and here is sending thread

public static class Send extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,Void> {
    Socket socket ;
    ObjectOutputStream outputStream;

    public Send(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        try {
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeObject(objects[0]);
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

 This two threads are sharing one socket.
```